# How to use `awk` to grep certain columns like these?

Tags: bash, awk

So basically I have some text like this:

```
[ 4] .init             PROGBITS        080481c0 0001c0 00002e 00  AX  0   0  4
[ 5] .plt              PROGBITS        080481f0 0001f0 000110 00  AX  0   0 16
[ 6] .text             PROGBITS        08048300 000300 07c95c 00  AX  0   0 16
[ 7] __libc_thread_fre PROGBITS        080c4c60 07cc60 000076 00  AX  0   0 16
[ 8] __libc_freeres_fn PROGBITS        080c4ce0 07cce0 000b2f 00  AX  0   0 16
[ 9] .fini             PROGBITS        080c5810 07d810 00001a 00  AX  0   0  4
[10] .rodata           PROGBITS        080c5840 07d840 019774 00   A  0   0 32
[11] __libc_thread_sub PROGBITS        080defb4 096fb4 000004 00   A  0   0  4
[12] __libc_subfreeres PROGBITS        080defb8 096fb8 00002c 00   A  0   0  4
[13] __libc_atexit     PROGBITS        080defe4 096fe4 000004 00   A  0   0  4
```

What I am trying to get is this:

```
.init                    080481c0 0001c0 00002e 
.plt                     080481f0 0001f0 000110 
.text                    08048300 000300 07c95c 
__libc_thread_fre        080c4c60 07cc60 000076 
__libc_freeres_fn        080c4ce0 07cce0 000b2f  
.fini                    080c5810 07d810 00001a 
.rodata                  080c5840 07d840 019774 
__libc_thread_sub        080defb4 096fb4 000004 
__libc_subfreeres        080defb8 096fb8 00002c  
__libc_atexit            080defe4 096fe4 000004
```

I tried something like this:

```
 awk '/PROGBITS/ {print $2,$4,$5,$6} '
```

but the problem is that, there is a space inside `[ 4]` .. , which means in the `4-9` line, I have to use

```
awk '/PROGBITS/ {print $3,$5,$6,$7} '
```

Is there anyway to use a **single** command while getting all the columns I want..?

Comment: If that space is your only problem, you'd be better off filtering it explicitly before it reaches awk. E.g. `sed -e 's/^\[ */\[/'`

Comment: `tr -s '\s[]' '\t' < "$input" | awk '/PROGBITS/{ print $2,$4,$5,$6}' | column -t`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `gnu awk` you have this elegant way to handle text with fixed width on fields.  It will also keep the formatting.

```
awk -v FIELDWIDTHS="5 18 16 8 7 8" '{print $2,$4,$5,$6}' file
.init              080481c0  0001c0  00002e
.plt               080481f0  0001f0  000110
.text              08048300  000300  07c95c
__libc_thread_fre  080c4c60  07cc60  000076
__libc_freeres_fn  080c4ce0  07cce0  000b2f
.fini              080c5810  07d810  00001a
.rodata            080c5840  07d840  019774
__libc_thread_sub  080defb4  096fb4  000004
__libc_subfreeres  080defb8  096fb8  00002c
__libc_atexit      080defe4  096fe4  000004
```

Comment: +1 - didn't know about `FIELDWIDTHS` (feature was actually introduced a long time ago, in version 2.13).

Comment: @mklement0 Its not very commonly used, but for this type of work, its perfect.

Answer (score 3):

You can also try:

```
awk '/PROGBITS/{print $(NF-9),$(NF-7),$(NF-6),$(NF-5)}' file
```

If you want to keep something readable, by choosing the columns width:

```
awk '/PROGBITS/{printf "%-18s %-10s %-10s %-10s\n", $(NF-9),$(NF-7),$(NF-6),$(NF-5)}' file
```

It is also not impossible that your file has `\t` (tabs) as field separators; if so, you may try:

```
awk -F"\t" '{print $2,$4,$5,$6}' file
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Clever, but you're missing the first desired output field, `$(NF-9)` (`$2`). Also, the trailing whitespace needed for column alignment is lost.

Comment: Thanks for updating; use of `printf` is a pragmatic solution; +1.

Answer (score 3):

If all you need is to **extract the columns as specified**, **`cut` will do**:

```
cut -c 6-22 -c 32-62 file
```

Answer (score 2):

If you can use `perl`:

```
perl -lne '/\] \K(.*)PROGBITS\s+(\w+)\s+(\w+)\s+(\w+)/ && print "$1 $2 $3 $4" '
```

In action:

```
perl -lne '/\] \K(.*)PROGBITS\s+(\w+)\s+(\w+)\s+(\w+)/ && print "$1 $2 $3 $4" ' file
.init              080481c0 0001c0 00002e
.plt               080481f0 0001f0 000110
.text              08048300 000300 07c95c
__libc_thread_fre  080c4c60 07cc60 000076
__libc_freeres_fn  080c4ce0 07cce0 000b2f
.fini              080c5810 07d810 00001a
.rodata            080c5840 07d840 019774
__libc_thread_sub  080defb4 096fb4 000004
__libc_subfreeres  080defb8 096fb8 00002c
__libc_atexit      080defe4 096fe4 000004
```

Comment: +1; `\K` is not needed, though. Your answer inspired my `sed` answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a field-separator option with `-F`:

`awk -F'^\\[ *[0-9]+\\] | +' '{printf "%-24s %-8s %-6s %-6s\n", $2, $4, $5, $6}' file`

The regular expression passed as the field-separator takes care of the possibility of numerical/spacial ambiguity in the beginning of each line.

Comment: Clever, but you should escape the `[` and `]` instances that are not part of a set: `^\[ *[0-9]+\] | +'`. Also, the trailing whitespace needed for column alignment is lost.

Comment: I too thought the outer `[` and `]` should be escaped, but I received warnings from `awk` when I escaped them. It works (warning-free) without the escaping. `printf` has been added for column alignment.

Comment: Thanks for updating; +1. Re escaping: I see. It's only GNU `awk` that issues the warning, but it's helpful: it indicates that _normal_ string parsing will simply "eat" the single `\ ` so that the `[` in the resulting regex is NOT escaped. In other words: in the case at hand, `[` and `\[` result in the _same_: an _unescaped_ `[`. Curiously, though, it still works - not sure why. That said, for proper escaping we need _2_ backlashes - so that one of them "survives" and is seen by the regex: `-F'^\\[ *[0-9]+\\] | +'`

Comment: Makes sense; double-backslashes it is. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply remove any whitespace right after the `[`:

```
sed 's_\[\s_[_'
```

Try,

```
echo '[ 1]' | sed 's_\[\s_[_'
```

It'll print `[1]`.

Comment: I don't think you want the `/g`. If you do, you may as well strip square braces altogether: `tr -d '[]'`

Comment: Well of course, but the `/g` means something I don't think you really mean. If there were a second `"[ "` on the line, would you necessarily want to strip the whitespace?

Comment: @kojiro Oh.. Didn't notice that, thanks for your comment, I already modified my answer.

Answer (score 1):

A `sed` solution (GNU `sed` and FreeBSD/OS X `sed`) - tip of the hat to [@Tiago's helpful Perl solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24613878/45375):

```
sed -E 's/^.*\] (.*)PROGBITS( +[^ ]+)( +[^ ]+)( +[^ ]+).*$/\1 \2 \3 \4/' file
```

- Uses a regular expression that matches the *entire* line, with capture groups (`(...)`) matching the data of interest (including preceding whitespace), and then replacing the line with only the data of interest - `\1` refers to the 1st capture group's match, `\2` to the 2nd, ...

---

Note that it *can* be done in a POSIX-compliant manner, but it gets ugly:

```
sed 's/^.*\] \(.*\)PROGBITS\( \{1,\}[^ ]\{1,\}\)\( \{1,\}[^ ]\{1,\}\)\( \{1,\}[^ ]\{1,\}\).*$/\1 \2 \3 \4/' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
awk '/PROGBITS/ {if (NF==12) print $3,$5,$6,$7; else print $2,$4,$5,$6}'
```

Comment: Clever and pragmatic, but the trailing whitespace needed for column alignment is lost.